# ScrollIntoView scrolls to the bottom of page instead of start of block

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I am using Javascript's scrollIntoView() to send to the start of a div on the page. Locally on MAMP it seems to work fine, but online (on Shopify) no matter what I do it scrolls to the bottom of the page.

I have checked that there isn't two elements with the same ID, I have tried with a different element, I have tried with another selector (document.getElementById('personal-data')), I have tried with simply the true argument.

```
document.querySelector("#personal-data").scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start",
    inline: "nearest"
});

document.querySelector("#personal-data").scrollIntoView(true);
```

I'm not sure what is happening there. Any help?

Comment: Would you like to share the URL ?

Comment: try doing document.querySelectorAll('#personal-data') and see if there are multiple elements with that id on the page.